# Octopress failed on running rake preview

Tags: macos, rake, octopress

It's a little wired that, I tried to install octopress, everything went very well, but I just can't use the `rake preview`. There are some information when I tried to view preview:

Server seems no problem at all:

```
bash-3.2$ rake preview
Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
Configuration from /Users/Gizak/Documents/oct/_config.yml
[2013-12-23 16:12:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-12-23 16:12:21] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
[2013-12-23 16:12:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5525 port=4000
Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public
[2013-12-23 16:12:22] regeneration: 93 files changed
>>> Change detected at 16:12:22 to: screen.scss
identical public/stylesheets/screen.css 

Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
- Travis Tilley

>>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2013 16:12:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0245
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2013 16:12:25] "GET /stylesheets/screen.css HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0028
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Dec/2013 16:12:25] "GET /javascripts/modernizr-2.0.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0012
```

You can see the response code is 200, BUT when I looked into the browser, I found that it just didn't do its job:
[image: OSX 10.9, Safari]

I never saw this kind of errors. I followed the octopress' instructions strictly to install it. Did I miss something?

SYS INFO:
OSX 10.9
Safari

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a known problem with Safari based on [this issue on Github](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1395).  The two suggested workarounds listed on that issue are:

1. Try hitting `http://localhost:4000` from Firefox or Chrome.
2. Install and use the Ruby Thin Server instead of the default WEBrick server.  A good set of instructions for making that change can be found in [this blog post](http://blog.geoffpetrie.com/blog/2012/10/14/octopress-change-the-default-preview-server/).